# Upgrading from Cassandea 1.1.9 to 1.2.18

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, datastax, bulkloader

I'm trying to upgrade from a 3 node 1.1.9 cluster to a 6 node 1.2.18 cluster.  Can sstableloader be used to stream from the existing cluster to the new cluster?  If so, what that the suggested method?  I keep getting the following when trying this:

partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner does not match system partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.  Note that the default partitioner starting with Cassandra 1.2 is Murmur3Partitioner, so you will need to edit that to match your old partitioner if upgrading.

It would appear that 1.1.9 doesn't have Murmur3Partitioner though, so I changed the partitioner on the new cluster to RandomPartitioner.  Even with that, I get the following error:

CLASSPATH=/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml:/root/lib_cass15/apache-cassandra-1.2.18.jar:/root/lib_cass15/guava-13.0.1.jar:/etc/cassandra/conf:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-1.1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-clientutil-1.1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-1.1.9.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/avro-1.4.0-sources-fixes.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-r08.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.0.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/stress.jar
Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:233)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:119)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:67)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_ring(Cassandra.java:1155)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_ring(Cassandra.java:1142)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:212)
        ... 2 more

Is there a way to get sstableloader to work?  If not, can someone point me to documentation explaining other ways to migrate the data/keyspaces?  I haven't been able to find any detailed docs.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is in stages:

First, upgrade your existing cluster to 1.2

Second, either snapshot your sstables on each existing node and copy them to the new nodes, or set up your new nodes as a data center attached to your existing nodes and let replication handle the loading.

Don't use sstable2json.